# mysql-connector-python results in SIGSEGV but mysql-connector does not

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, segmentation-fault, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to transition from pip install mysql-connector version 2.1.7 to mysql-connector-python 8.0.15 in Python3. It installs fine but I keep getting 'interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV'. I am using sqlalchemy:

```
db_uri = ConfigFetcher.get_db_uri()
engine_obj = create_engine(db_uri, pool_recycle=3600)
ENGINE = engine_obj
SESSION_MAKER = sessionmaker(bind=engine_obj)
```

in requirements.txt I have mysql-connector-python==8.0.15 and in my Dockerfile I have 
`# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r /event_git/requirements.txt`

Does anyone have any idea how to prevent the seg fault?